# Signed Route not defined laravel

Tags: laravel

I am testing Signed route.

im my *resources >> views >> web.php* i have my route two routes

```
Route::get('/unsubscribe/{user?}', function ($user='') {
     return view('about');
});

Route::get('test', function () {
    echo URL::signedRoute('unsubscribe', ['user' => 1]);
});
```

when i hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/ to test my Signed URL i am getting error

> Route [unsubscribe] not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: (add name to the route)

```
Route::get('/unsubscribe/{user?}', function ($user='') {
    return view('about');
})->name('unsubscribe');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved this issue myself, hopefully it'll help someone.

I'd run "php artisan queue:work" in the background, THEN changed the routes, so even though the route was appearing in "php artisan route:list", it wasn't picked up by the queue worker.

I just stopped the worked and restarted it.